# Saving value from anchor element into a variable

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to save the value of an anchor element into a variable, but haven't had any luck accomplishing it.  Here's the code anchor and the code that I'm trying to use:

```
<html>
<body> 

<a href="/page" class="foo">Widget <span class='amount'>$98.00</span></a>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("amount");
    alert(x);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My expectation is that when the alert fires, that I get $98.00 in the pop-up, but all I get is "null".  I've changed the value in document.getElementbyId using "span", "class" or "a", but what I get is that it's undefined or null.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Ridder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need an `id` (`<span id='amount'>`) not a `class` because you use `getElementById`
- Your code only selects the element, to get the content you need [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) or [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

See it here:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("amount").textContent;
alert(x);
```

```html
<a href="/page" class="foo">Widget <span id='amount'>$98.00</span></a>
```

---

Since you can't change the markup, you have to use a class selector:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0].textContent;
alert(x);
```

```html
<a href="/page" class="foo">Widget <span class='amount'>$98.00</span></a>
```

Bear in mind, `document.getElementsByClassName("amount")[0]` only selects the first `.amount` element in the document, if you have more of them, be careful to select the right one.

Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thanks Shomz for the suggestion, but unfortunately, I can't make that change on the site.  Is there any other options for gathering the data value without making any changes to the anchor tag?

Comment: Sure, you can loop over the array of elements returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('amount')` and do the same thing.

Comment: Shomz, this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much for the quick response and for the help.  It is really appreciated.